# Como compilar c++ com biblioteca SFML dentro do proprio projeto

Tags: c++, jogos, gcc, makefile, sfml

Olá pessoas que gostam de programar. estou com um problema que até agora pesquisando no pai dos burro (Google) não consegui resolver. eu estou fazendo um joguinho como parte da avaliação da materia de linguagem de programação 1. porém não sei como linkar (Compilar) corretamente o jogo, com a biblioteca SFML dentro da pasta do projeto. Eu instalei o SFML no linux (elementary) e estou compilando diretamente pelo codeblocks, só que eu quero fazer um makefile para compilar o projeto de forma a usar também a biblioteca dentro da pasta do projeto, de forma a que mesmo quem não tenha o sfml instalado no computador consiga compilar sem problemas. eu sei que quando o sfml está instalado a gente compila mais ou menos assim.

```
g++ -Wall src/main.cpp src/game.cpp -I include -o bin/app -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics
```

mas desse geito só funciona se a biblioteca estiver instalada no sistema. Tem como eu fazer uma pasta lib e colocar o SFML lá e compilá-lo? espero que tenha ficado claro minha dúvida. um abraço a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, basta utilizar o path de onde está a lib que você deseja utilizar com o argumento -L + diretório

```
g++ -Wall src/main.cpp src/game.cpp -I include -o bin/app -L lib/SFML-2.3.2 -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics
```

Só lembrando que as libs deverão ser distribuidas junto com o binário caso sejam linkadas dinamicamente.